# JavaScript sort array item after specific array id

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am sorting an array of object using the date values inside each object.
I now have an edge case, if the`noDate`
property is set to true, that object shall be sorted after the object with the id 2.

An object looks something like this:

```
{
    id: 1 // just simple ids 1...99
    date: ...
    noDate: true // true or false
}
```

Currently its sorted like this, but that does not provide the logic I need.

```
data.sort((a, b) => (!a.noDate - !b.noDate) || new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
```

Comment: perhaps `data.sort((a, b) => a.noDate ? -1 : new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date) )`

Comment: @mplungjan I want to sort the object with the noDate value set to true to be sorted after the object with id 2

Comment: do you have some example data?

Comment: @NinaScholz I created a snippet here, hope it is more understandable now :) https://kopy.io/N6q9Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort first to get all `noDate: true` at top of the array and then map a new array to get all top items after `id: 2` object. This approach needs a finally

```js
let
    data = [
        { id: 0, noDate: true },
        { id: 1, date: new Date('2021-10-30') },
        { id: 2, date: new Date('2020-10-30') },
        { id: 3, noDate: true },
        { id: 4, date: new Date('2021-09-30') },
        { id: 5, date: new Date('2020-09-15') },
        { id: 6, noDate: true }
    ];

data = data
    .sort((a, b) => !a.noDate - !b.noDate || a.date - b.date)
    .flatMap((a => o => {
        if (o.noDate) { a.push(o); return []; }
        if (o.id === 2) return [o, a];
        return o;
    })([]))
    .flat();

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.noDate ? -1 : new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))
```

Or if you want to sort by two field first **sortNumber** and then sorting by **date**

```
list.sort((a, b) => a.sortNumber == b.sortNumber ? new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date): a.sortNumber - b.sortNumber)
```

Comment: I want to sort the object with the noDate value set to true to be sorted after the object with id 2, does this actually solve this or am I understanding something wrong?